# Cronjob Syntax Error for Database Backup

Tags: php, cron, mysql, cpanel, jail-shell

All I want is to backup the database using cronjob. I keep getting this error.

Error
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Cronjob

```
root mysqldump -e --user=t***b --password=1*** --all-databases | gzip | uuencode `date-database.sql.gz | mail -s "`dateweb1_iepe-wp.sql.gz mysqldump backup" ***@gmail.com
```

Comment: Is this working on your command line ? it seems that you have a copy/paste trouble, i think. ` shouldn't be there or is at the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think jailshell has a problem with shell substitution.  I worked around this by creating the command in php.

```
echo "<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); passthru( '/usr/bin/mysqldump -uXXX -pYYY db_name > /home/mysql_backups/backup-'.date(DATE_ATOM));" | php -q
```

This worked for me inside a cPanel cron job, which uses jailshell